# Android secure fingerprint authentication

Tags: android, security, encryption, android-biometric-prompt

I try to write code to implement secure fingerprint authentication to prevent bypass (i.e. with Frida).
I can't realize which secure data should I encrypt/decrypt in function onAuthenticationSucceeded () of BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback?
Can anyone give me an example? I have read that it should be some secure data, but I don't understand what exactly should I use. If it's authorization token, what should I do with it?

Comment: The best way is to use code that can not be bypassed. Use e.g. AndroidKeystore and place a key in there that requires biometrics. And the key is used to decrypt data required for the protected action